# Configure multistore in subdirectories

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

How can I config magento 2.1 CE multi store in subdirectories with Shared cart and user manager.

For example:

- mysite.com/men
- mysite.com/women
- mysite.com/kids

and all of these subdirectories have one Shared cart and user manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to create multi-store:

Create Stores:

1. ADMIN: click Stores > Settings > All Stores.
2. Click `Create Store`
3. Enter store name in `Name` and select the website name  from `Web Site`dropdown. And Select Category from `Root category` dropdown.
4. Click the `Save Store` and repeat this for 3 stores

Now. You have to create store-views for your stores as follow:

1. Click on `Create Store View`
2. Chose name of store from `Store` which to associate this store view.
3. Enter the `Name` and `Code` of store and chose `Enable` from Status.
4. Click 'Save Store View' and repeat this step 2 more times.

You can refer [Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html) for complete details and comment if there is any confusion.

You dont need Step [7] of the documentation.